# QtCreator subdirs project linker error for library dependency

Tags: qt, qt6

- Platform: Windows 11
- Qt Version: 6.5.1
- QtCreator Version: 10.0.2

I'm playing around with Qt Creator and QMake project structures and am running into a linker issue (undefined reference) when compiling an app that attempts to make use of items defined in a cpp in a library. I'm using the subdirs project type to house related subprojects with the following structure:

```
parentProject
   |- parentProject.pro
   |- coreApp
   |     |- coreApp.pro
   |     |- main.cpp
   |     |- mainwindow.cpp
   |- coreLib
         |-coreLib.pro
         |- corelib.h
         |- corelib.cpp
         |- coreLib_global.h
         |- Temp.h
         |- temp2.h
         |- temp2.cpp
```

Parent project being the subdirs project maintains references to the various subprojects

```
#parentProject.pro

TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    coreApp \
    coreLib

coreApp.depends+=coreLib
```

The coreLib was created using the `QtCreator New Project -> Library -> C++ Library` wizard and virtually nothing was changed. Only the temp files were added to play around with things (posted below).

```
#coreLib.pro

QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += CORELIB_LIBRARY

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    corelib.cpp \
    temp2.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Temp.h \
    coreLib_global.h \
    corelib.h \
    temp2.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

The coreApp was created using the `QtCreator New Project -> Application (Qt) -> Qt Widgets Application` and essentially left untouched. The only changes I'd made are as follows:

- `coreApp project -> Add Library -> Internal Library -> select coreLib` with everything else in that dialog left at the default
- `main.cpp` updated to make call to my test classes in coreLib

```
#coreApp.pro

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

TRANSLATIONS += \
    coreApp_en_US.ts
CONFIG += lrelease
CONFIG += embed_translations

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../coreLib/release/ -lcoreLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../coreLib/debug/ -lcoreLib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../coreLib/ -lcoreLib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../coreLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../coreLib
```

And the updated to `main.cpp` can literally be written out as:

```
//main.cpp

//snip
#include "corelib.h"
#include "temp2.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CoreLib();
    std::cout << "RESULT: " << Temp2().sub(1, 2) << std::endl;
    // snip
}
```

The files in coreLib are as rudimentary as it gets

```
//corelib.h - as per what was generated
#ifndef CORELIB_H
#define CORELIB_H

#include "coreLib_global.h"

class CORELIB_EXPORT CoreLib
{
public:
    CoreLib();
};

#endif // CORELIB_H
```

```
//corelib.cpp - as per generated just with the cout added
#include "corelib.h"
#include <iostream>

CoreLib::CoreLib()
{
    std::cout << "NOT HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
//Temp.h
#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

inline int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

#endif // TEMP_H
```

```
//temp2.h
#ifndef TEMP2_H
#define TEMP2_H


class Temp2
{
public:
    Temp2();

    int sub(int x, int y);
};

#endif // TEMP2_H
```

```
//temp2.cpp
#include "temp2.h"

Temp2::Temp2()
{

}

int Temp2::sub(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}
```

What I'm Experiencing:

- changes I make to `corelib.cpp` can be access and changes are reflected (i.e.: if I change the cout in the constructor I can see the change when I launch coreApp)
- changes in the header files are seen in coreApp and the Temp::add() function works as expected
- if I try to move the implementation of Temp::add() to `Temp.cpp` I get a linker error relating to unresolved reference to Temp::add()
- if I try to do anything with Temp2 I get an unresolved linker error to Temp2::Temp2()

My confusion:

- the fact that `corelib.h` and `corelib.cpp` look to be working indicates that the coreLib.dll is created and accessed by coreApp
- the headers can be seen/accessed since Temp::add() works when I leave it implemented in `Temp.h`
- `temp2.cpp` is getting compiled (I can see `temp2.o` in the build directory with the expected timestamp)

It feels like other cpp files while compiled are not included in the generated dll. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's the `coreLib_global.h` that is the crux of the matter. If the class/header definition makes use of that it will be available for use outside of the library. Meaning temp2.h becomes:

```
//temp2.h
#ifndef TEMP2_H
#define TEMP2_H

#include "coreLib_global.h"

class CORELIB_EXPORT Temp2
{
public:
    Temp2();

    int sub(int x, int y);
};

#endif // TEMP2_H
```

And by marking the class as a CORELIB_EXPORT it becomes accessible to outside of the library. Without it, it can only be used internally (or purely as a header).

More detail can be found in the [QT Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sharedlibrary.html).